# Motivation for this solution to a British olympiad problem

Tags: contest-math, problem-solving

I was doing question 6 from this BMO1 paper: https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/home/bmo1-2019.pdf and I didn't manage to get it. Then I looked at the solution and found the solution. I can see how the solution works but there is a step that I cannot see how anyone would have ever thought to have tried. I'm trying to improve at problem solving so I'd like to know how I would be supposed to think of something like that.

> Ada the ant starts at a point $O$ on a plane. At the start of each minute she chooses North, South, East or West, and marches $1$ metre in that direction. At the end of $2018$ minutes she finds herself back at $O$. Let $n$ be the number of possible journeys which she could have made. What is the highest power of $10$ which divides $n$.

(READ FULL QUESTION BEFORE GOING TO VIDEO) Here is the video solution: https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/solutions/bmo1-2019/ The step I am confused about how someone could think of it is the part at 4:15 in the solution video. How is someone meant to think of creating a new set of coordinates ((x + y), (x - y))? I just can't see how you would make that jump or even think to try that. If you want to try the problem yourself first, maybe you will be more able to explain to me how you realised that you needed to make that step however if you want you can just look at the video solution.

Comment: There are many problems like this.  We don't know how to proceed, and then there's "a trick", and then the problem becomes easy.  A change of coordinates is in the bag of tricks, and as you progress, you'll find your bag of tricks getting bigger.

Comment: oh thats interesting because I have actually thought about the idea of a "bag of tricks" before. However the tricks I have come across tended to be much more general, maybe I just need to do alot more practice to get tricks as detailed as this. Did you manage to see this was one of those tricks yourself or did you  notice from the video solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried to solve the problem in my head, and thought of the change-of-coordinate trick within a minute or two (at which point I stopped, knowing that it is only computation starting from there).

To answer your question of "how does one come up with it", let me try to retrace the intuitive process in my mind. I thought roughly as follows:

"OK, so a point on the Euclidean plane is described by a pair of numbers (its coordinates). So a path is a sequence of pairs of numbers. Actually, it looks like the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate do not interact at all here - so we might as well encode paths as pairs of sequences of numbers.

OK, now what are the precise conditions that such a pair of sequences of numbers must satisfy in order to provide a solution?

Answer: $((x_1, \ldots, x_{2018}), (y_1, \ldots, y_{2018}))$ is a valid pair if and only if every term of each sequence is $-1$, $0$, or $1$, the sum of each sequence is $0$, and, for every $i$, <s>$x_i$ and $y_i$ are never simultaneously nonzero</s> exactly one of $x_i$ and $y_i$ is nonzero.

Dang! in fact, it turns out that the two sequences do interact - and in a rather messy way. This last condition seems hard to take into account when solving the problem.

So let us start by solving a simpler problem, which consists of two independent copies of the one-dimensional version of this problem: so let us allow $x_i$ and $y_i$ to take only the values $\pm 1$, but with all four combinations allowed.

Oh wait --- but actually this is the same as the original problem, just rotated 45 degrees (and rescaled)! So here we are."

Comment: ok i have some questions, so firstly, what do you mean by the x coordinate and y coordinate do not "interact" at all?

Comment: It means that you could solve the problem first by focusing exclusively on the x coordinate (and forgetting about the y coordinate), then by focusing exclusively on the y coordinate (and forgetting about the x), and then by combining these two results together in an "obvious" way. More precisely, once you make the change of coordinates, the total number of 2D paths returning to 0 is equal to the number of 1D paths in the x coordinate returning to 0, times the number of 1D paths in the y coordinate returning to 0.

Comment: ok thanks so next you write, "what are the precise conditions that...  are never simultaneously nonzero.". Why is it that every term must be 1, 0 or -1 for the sequence of numbers to provide a solution? this is what the sequence would be if you use x+y or x-y coordinates but if you are using normal coordinates, to create a satisfactory pair of sequences of numbers this is not the case

Comment: off topic sidenote: "how do you type with the notation you have used in your question e.g. x subscript i

Comment: The coordinates of the $i$-th step are $(x_i, y_i)$. If it is north, you have $(x_i, y_i) = (0,1)$. If it is east, you have $(x_i, y_i) = (1,0)$. If it is south, you have $(x_i, y_i) = (0,-1)$. If it is west, you have $(x_i, y_i) = (-1,0)$. In all four cases, you see that $x_i$ is either $-1$, $0$ or $1$; and so is $y_i$. However, there is the additional restriction that $x_i$ and $y_i$ cannot be BOTH nonzero (northeast etc. is not allowed), nor (I initially overlooked this! I edited my answer) both zero (standing still for one minute is not allowed either).

Comment: Concerning math notation: you can use LaTeX commands; see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Ok thanks for the reference. What is confusing me is, why do the coordinates have to be in terms of increase or decrease relative to the previous position? e.g. if the ant is at (5, 2) and moves right one space i would write its next coordinate as (6, 2) however you would write (1, 0) as you are writing the coordinates relative to the previous position. why have you done this?

Comment: In order to have the condition express in a simpler way. This reasoning focuses more on the increments of position than on the absolute position; so I chose to encode everything in terms of the position increments, to avoid having expressions like "$X_i - X_{i-1}$" all over the place.

Comment: wow sorry I have been gone for so long I have been doing some things but ok so, you have explained why you have expressed the coordinates in that way but I still never would have thought of it myself however someone did say that it is like one trick from a bag of tricks that you build up from doing problem solving, do you think you would agree?

Comment: I don't know. I think it is more like a key idea in mathematical problem solving (and in mathematics in general): when, in the expressions that you manipulate, some pattern keeps appearing and hinders your progress, try to abstract away that pattern with an appropriate change of notation. For example, here, if you try to reason in terms of position increments, you see differences like "$X_i - X_{i-1}$" everywhere - so you give a name to this difference (for example $x_i$), and then re-encode everything in terms of the $x_i$'s.

Comment: oh ok so its not a particular case where you would know "this is what i need to do" its more of just knowing that generally a change in notation could help

Answer (score 18):

The video solution is really clever, but you can also solve the problem by just slogging along.  As the presenter said at the beginning, we have to choose $2k$ east-west moves, $k$ of which will be west, and then we have to choose $1009-k$ north moves.  The remaining $1009-k$ moves will be south.  This gives $$
n=\sum_{k=0}^{1009}{2018\choose k}{2018 -k\choose k}{2018-2k\choose1009-k}$$ possible paths.  Let's try to simplify this before giving up.  We have $$\begin{align}
n&=\sum_{k=0}^{1009}{2018!\over k!(2018-k)!}{(2018-k)!\over k!(2018-2k)!}{(2018-2k)!\over (1009-k)!(1009-k)!}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{1009}{2018!\over k!(1009-k)!k!(1009-k)!}\\&={2018!\over 1009!1009!}\sum_{k=0}^{1009}\left({1009!\over k!(1009-k)!}\right)^2\\&={2018\choose 1009}\sum_{k=0}^{1009}{1009\choose k}^2\end{align}$$

Up to here, I think it is pretty straightforward.  Those factors of $k!(1009-k)!$ should suggest trying to express things in terms of ${1009\choose k}$.  Now comes a trick, [Vandermonde's identity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)  Even if you don't recall exactly what it says, if you've ever seen the proof, you should be able to recreate the formula. $$
\sum_{k=0}^{1009}{1009\choose k}^2=\sum_{k=0}^{1009}{1009\choose k}{1009\choose 1009-k}={2018\choose 1009}$$  The last equality comes because to choose $1009$ elements from a collection of $2018$ we can choose $k$ from the first $1009$ and the remaining $1009-k$ from the second $1009.$

Putting it all together, we have $$n={2018\choose1009}^2$$

I am not at all clever, so this is how I did it.

Comment: This is exactly how I would have done it as well, because once you get to the summation step, it's hard to resist finishing the evaluation in a mechanical way.

Comment: This is actually how I approached the problem as well and it seems from heropups comment, this is a more typical approach, however I only got to the summation before the point that you factor out the 2018!/1009!1009!, I dont see how you managed to take this out. Also Im not sure if it would be valid to use the vandermondes identity as the olympiad is usually made to be doable by a level maths students which i have done but have not heard of this

Comment: I multiplied and divided by $(1009!)^2$.  You don't have to have heard of the identity to understand the proof, do you?

Comment: oh ok sorry i see it now

Answer (score 7):

You can just count how many possible paths the ant can take by assuming it makes $k$ steps to the east and $k$ to the west, then deciding the order of the east-west paths, similarly those of the north-south ($1009-k$) and finally deciding how to mix both sequences. Everything can hence be expressed in terms of binomial coefficients:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N}C_k^{2k}C_{N-k}^{2N-2k}C_{2k}^{2N}=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}\frac{(2N-2k)!}{((N-k)!)^2}\frac{(2N)!}{(2k)!(2N-2k)!}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{(2N)!}{(k!)^2((N-k)!)^2}$$
$$=\frac{(2N)!}{(N!)^2}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\left(C_N^k\right)^2=\left(C_{2N}^N\right)^2$$
where $N=1009$.

Then you can compute the $2$- and $5$-adic valuations with the usual formula:

$$\nu_p(A!)=\left\lfloor A/p \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor A/p^2 \right\rfloor + \ldots $$

So:

$$\nu_5(2018!)=502, \nu_5(1009!)=250$$
$$\nu_2(2018!)=2011, \nu_2(1009!)=1002$$

So the highest power is $10^4$.

Comment: this is a similar approach to the answer above however it seems you have evaluated the summation in a different way. I havent done the maths that you have used for the second part before so I couldnt follow but i can see that the answer is correct. However, the olympiad is supposed to be doable for a level maths students and at least in the edexcel a level maths i didnt cover this. So so far, the only method i have found that uses basic enough maths is the one used in the solution and that is the one with the step that seemed unspottable to me

Comment: I believe that binomial coefficients and combinatorics are within the prerequisites of Olympiad. Probably less so for $p$-adic valuations, but basic arithmetics definitely. So all in all it seems more probable to me that an A-level math student will use a "brute force" approach rather than a clever (and unspottable) shortcut.

Comment: oh ok i didnt know that so that would be one way of doing it then

Answer (score 3):

A good idea for whenever you don't know how to start a combinatorics problem that asks you to compute something for a very high integer (in this case, 2018) is to compute some small cases and look for a pattern.  To get started on this one, note that the number of paths of length $n$ to any given point is the sum of paths of length $n-1$ to it's neighboring points.  This makes it easy to compute small cases:

```
n=0                         
                1           
n=1                         
                1           
            1       1       
                1           
n=2                         
                1           
            2       2       
        1       4       1   
            2       2       
                1           
n=3                         
                1           
            3       3       
        3       9       3   
    1       9       9       1
        3       9       3   
            3       3       
                1
```

See the pattern yet?  The edges are rows of Pascal's triangle, and the inner diagonals are just multiples of the same row of Pascal's triangle.  Prove this by induction.  The middle element (for even numbers $n$ of steps) will be just the square of the central binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{n/2}^2$.  Evaluate the pattern for $n=2018$, look for the highest power of $5$, and you've got your answer.

I see mention of a coordinate change in several answers and comments.  From the pictures above, it's clear why that might be a good idea.  However, I think it's not really necessary once you see the pattern.

---

Commentary: Since the OP is interested in problem solving strategies, one minor metaprinciple I would mention is that binomial coefficients and Pascal's triangle come up a lot in lattice path problems, so it is well advised to be expecting them.  Another neat example (actually two examples, which closely related to each other) are the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) and [Bertrand's ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem), which I would highly recommend studying for anyone interested in competition math.

Comment: sorry i have been gone for so long i have been abit busy. ok so I understood up to the diagram but I cant seem to figure out what the numbers in the diagram are representing?

Comment: For $n=3$, shouldn't the inner square be made of $9$'s (rather than $6$'s)?

Comment: @IliaSmilga Yes, thanks--good catch.

Comment: @cooldud The numbers are the number of paths to a given point in the plane.  So for $n=1$, the diagram is showing that there is one path of length $n=1$ to the points $(\pm 1,0)$ and $(0,\pm 1)$.  For $n=2$, the diagram is showing that there is one path to $(\pm 2, 0)$, one path to $(0,\pm 2)$, two paths to $\pm (1,\pm 1)$, and four paths to the origin $(0,0)$.  Similarly for $n=3$ it shows that there are nine paths to $(\pm 1,0)$, one path to $(\pm 3,0)$, etc.

Comment: oh ok i understand now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let the no. of $N$ moves $= S$ moves $=k $ and $E$  moves $= W$ moves $=1009-k $. Clearly grouping $k$ with $k$ will be messy so lets group $k$ with $1009-k$. So lets just pick $1009 
([k]+ [1009-k])$ moves for N and E and the remaining $1009$ will correspond for S and W. Clearly, there is${2018\choose 1009}$ ways of doing this.

Now, we have selected $1009$ for N and E and $1009$ for S and W. Now we only need to see in each of these groups which positions are for which direction. Let us find the no. of ways to pick the exact positions of N and W among each of the groups of $1009$ and the remaining positions will be filled by E and S in the respective groups. Since, there are a total of $2018$ positions and we are choosing $([k]+ [1009-k])= 1009$ , the no. of ways we can do this is:

$${2018\choose 1009}$$

Now we need to just multiply this by our initial ways of separating $2018$ into the groups of $1009$ for both sets.

Thus our Final Answer would be : $${{2018\choose 1009}}^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers above, but a slightly more explicit counting approach to the above; also tried to explain everything fully for complete clarity, including links to useful resources.

Let $x_{N}=$ no. of north moves, and $x_{S},x_{W},x_{E}$ be defined similarly.
As she returns to O in 2018 moves, her displacement is 0m and so $x_N=x_S, \ x_W=x_E.$
Also, $\ x_N+x_{S}+x_{W}+x_{E}=2018$ as that is the total no. of moves.
If $x_N=x$ say, it must then follow that $x_S=x$ and that $x_W=\frac{1}{2}(2018-2x)=1009-x=x_E$.
Note that $x$ cannot exceed 1009, as it is clear that
$$
x_W=x_E \geqslant 0, \ x_N=x_S \geqslant 0
\\\iff \ 1009-x\geqslant 0, \ x \geqslant 0
\\\iff 0\leqslant x\leqslant1009 \ \blacksquare
$$
For some given $x$ in the established interval, we can arrange the order in which the moves are made in multiple different ways (that's the question lol). Consider the general arrangement $\underbrace{NN\ldots N}_{x}\underbrace{SS\ldots S}_{x}\underbrace{WW\ldots W}_{1009-x}\underbrace{EE\ldots E}_{1009-x}$.

There are $2018!$ ways to arrange the above. However, in any given arrangement, we will be overcounting due to repetition of the same symbol (N, S, W, E occur multiple times as shown), as you could arrange within any one of the 4 symbols any way you like and obtain the same initial arrangement (intuitively, swap any of the 2 E's and you can't notice a dfference). So to only count each such arrangement once, we must divide $2018!$ by the number of possible rearrangements of each symbol in the above arrangement. Therefore there are
$$
\dfrac{2018!}{x!x!(1009-x)!(1009-x)!}=\dfrac{2018!}{x!^2(1009-x)!^2}
$$
total ways to arrange a general arrangement above.
Now, to determine $n$ all that is required is to sum the expression just found over all integers such that $0\leqslant x \leqslant 1009$.
$$
\begin{align}
\therefore n &= \sum_{x=0}^{1009} \dfrac{2018!}{x!^2(1009-x)!^2}
\\ &= \dfrac{2018!}{1009!^2} \sum_{x=0}^{1009} \dfrac{1009!^2}{(x!(1009-x)!)^2}
\\ &= \binom{2018}{1009} \sum_{x=0}^{1009} \binom{1009}{x}^2
\end{align}
$$
To help evaluate the remaining sum, by the binomial theorem, we get $(1+x)^\gamma=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\gamma}\binom{\gamma}{k}x^k\implies (1+x)^{2\gamma}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2\gamma}\binom{2\gamma}{k}x^k$
but
$$
\begin{align}
(1+x)^{2\gamma}&=((1+x)^\gamma)^2
\\\implies  \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2\gamma}\binom{2\gamma}{k}x^k &=\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\gamma}\binom{\gamma}{k}x^k\right)^2
\end{align}
$$
consider the coefficient of $x^\gamma$ on the left and right:
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{2\gamma}{\gamma} &= \binom{\gamma}{0}\binom{\gamma}{\gamma}+\binom{\gamma}{1}\binom{\gamma}{\gamma-1}+\ldots +\binom{\gamma}{\gamma-1}\binom{\gamma}{1}+\binom{\gamma}{\gamma}\binom{\gamma}{0}
\\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\gamma \binom{\gamma}{k}\binom{\gamma}{\gamma-k}
\\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\gamma \binom{\gamma}{k}\binom{\gamma}{k} 
\\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\gamma \binom{\gamma}{k}^2
\end{align}
$$
This is actually a special case of a common combinatorial identity, known as [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), which can be proven similarly.
So now, we know that $\displaystyle \sum_{x=0}^{1009}\binom{1009}{x}^2=\binom{2(1009)}{1009}=\binom{2018}{1009}$.

$$
\therefore n = \binom{2018}{1009}^2
$$

To obtain the final answer, finding how many times 10 divides $n$, we need to find the number of times BOTH 2 and 5 divide $n$ as $10=2\times5$.
Using [p-adic valuation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjosJG_ubntAhUNYsAKHazzC-cQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FP-adic_order&usg=AOvVaw1VWz3JZY1woSycIDpyzLeA), this number will just be
$$
\begin{align}
\min\{\nu_2(n),\nu_5(n)\} &=\min\left\{\nu_2\left( \binom{2018}{1009}^2\right),\nu_5\left( \binom{2018}{1009}^2\right)\right\}
\\ &= \min\left\{2\nu_2\left( \binom{2018}{1009}\right),2\nu_5\left( \binom{2018}{1009}\right)\right\}
\end{align}
$$
We have that, by [Legendre's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) (line 4)
$$
\begin{align}
\\\nu_2\left(\binom{2018}{1009}\right) &= \nu_2\left(\frac{2018!}{(1009!)^2}\right)
\\ &= \nu_2(2018!)-\nu_2((1009!)^2)
\\ &= \nu_2(2018!)-2\nu_2(1009!)
\\ &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor\dfrac{2018}{2^k}\right\rfloor-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor\dfrac{1009}{2^k}\right\rfloor
\\ &= \sum_{k=1}^{10} \left\lfloor\dfrac{1009}{2^{k-1}}\right\rfloor-2\sum_{k=1}^{9} \left\lfloor\dfrac{1009}{2^k}\right\rfloor
\\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{9} \left\lfloor\dfrac{1009}{2^k}\right\rfloor-2\sum_{k=1}^{9} \left\lfloor\dfrac{1009}{2^k}\right\rfloor
\\ &= \left\lfloor \dfrac{1009}{2^0} \right\rfloor-\sum_{k=1}^{9} \lfloor2^{10-k}-2^{4-k}+2^{-k}\rfloor
\\ &= 1009-\sum_{k=1}^{9} \lfloor2^{10-k}-2^{4-k}\rfloor
\\ &= 1009-\sum_{k=1}^{4} (2^{10-k}-2^{4-k})-\sum_{k=5}^{9} (2^{10-k}-1)
\\ &= 1009-\sum_{k=1}^{9} 2^{10-k}+\sum_{k=1}^{4} 2^{4-k}+\sum_{k=5}^{9} 1
\\ &= 1009-\sum_{k=1}^{9} 2^{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{4} 2^{k}+5
\\ &= 1014-\dfrac{2(2^9-1)}{2-1}+\dfrac{2(2^4-1)}{2-1}
\\ &= 1014+2-2^{10}+2^5-2
\\ &=1014-1024+32
\\ &= 22
\end{align}
$$
and that
$$
\begin{align}
\\\nu_5\left(\binom{2018}{1009}\right) &= \nu_5\left(\frac{2018!}{(1009!)^2}\right)
\\ &= \nu_5(2018!)-\nu_5((1009!)^2)
\\ &= \nu_5(2018!)-2\nu_5(1009!)
\\ &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor\dfrac{2018}{5^k}\right\rfloor-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor\dfrac{1009}{5^k}\right\rfloor
\\ &= \sum_{k=1}^{4} \left\lfloor\dfrac{2018}{5^{k}}\right\rfloor-2\sum_{k=1}^{4} \left\lfloor\dfrac{1009}{5^k}\right\rfloor
\\ &= 403+80+16+3-2(201+40+8+1)
\\ &= 502-500
\\ &=2.
\end{align}
$$

So finally, we get the desired answer as
$$
\begin{align}
\min\{\nu_2(n),\nu_5(n)\} &=\min\{2(22),2(2)\}
\\ &= 4
\end{align}
$$